# Chaos theory in politics

Tags: political-theory

I have read and seen articles on this topic, but when I wanted to search for some specific examples recently happened or in history, I cannot find any.

As I know, inside politics, a chain of events with unpredictable outcomes is considered as chaotic events. Is this true? If not, what exactly or more does chaotic theory mean inside politics?

What are some examples that can easily be said 'this is chaotic' ?

Comment: The non-political, technical definition of chaos is very specific, and has to do with exponential divergence between close initial conditions of a deterministic system. It's not just about unpredictability.

Comment: If we are just talking about predictability, what kind of events are there in politics where you can actually predict the outcomes?

Comment: I am not an expert on politics but isn't every action done with an aim to achieve? Also if there is no event which you can not predict outcomes, does that mean all political events are chaotic? Isn't there a more specific definition inside politics for chaos theory?

Comment: `isn't every action done with an aim to achieve?` In politics you have multiple players who probably have very different or even opposite aims, and which act upon those aims. It is not an experiment that proceeds regardless of the observer's opinion, so you cannot even state an unanimous "aim". Also, in many cases part of the starting conditions are not even known.

Comment: The answer is probably "nothing at all" because political processes are not well suited to mathematical modelling.   However some economic models are chaotic https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.3492.pdf  I suggest: delete this question, rephrase in terms of economics and ask there.

Comment: @Raditz_35 - death and taxes? :P

Comment: I am not sure if you are looking for a specific term "chaos theory" in political science, or if you ask how chaotic systems influence policy making.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as too broad, due to its open ended nature and demonstrated misunderstanding of chaos theory. Have you conducted a modicrum of research on this topic? Just in searching "is chaos theory applicable to politics," the returns included  news articles and peer reviewed papers. Google Scholar has books on the issue as well. Consider looking there, narrowing what it is you don't know, and returning with a clarified question.

Answer (score 2):

Chaos theory involves deterministic systems whose outcomes are highly sensitive to small, almost impossible to measure, differences in the initial conditions. It excludes, e.g., stochastic systems which are truly random (e.g. as in quantum mechanics).

Few political theory concepts are sufficiently well described quantitatively to fit this model, but sometimes people look to the broad conclusions of chaos theory to try to describe phenomena such as the long term impact of close elections.

One of the key concepts in chaos theory that can have application of political science, at least by analogy, is the concept of an "attractor."

Often, even though the exact deterministic mathematical evolution of a system is chaotic, all of the paths that start in a particular general region ultimately end up coming close to a particular pattern called an attractor sooner or later in its path, even though the way that the chaotic mix of different paths taken differs greatly based upon slight differences in initial conditions.

(In politics the mathematical functions would usually be defined in something called "phase space" such as a graph with a party's percentage of seats in Congress v. extent to which legislation is liberal, rather than in physical space.)

For example, the common place notion that a nation's political leanings engages in pendulum swings from liberal to conservative and back again over time, gussied up to note that the direction of that swing can be strongly influenced by the outcome of a close election, could be compared to a chaotic system with a sinusoidal attractor.

As another example, there are some situations in legislative voting where Arrow's Paradox applies and the order in which questions are posed determines the outcome. To the extent that opinion is quite evenly divided and something like who manages to get into the chamber first in the morning based upon traffic in the capitol determines who gets to pose a question first, you could consider the outcome of the vote to be chaotic.

But, honestly, there is very little that chaos theory can add to political science that more pedestrian non-mathematical methods can't do just as well, because few systems in politics are tightly deterministic and described by well formulated equations.

I've never personally seen a political science article applying chaos theory, although there are some articles out there. See e.g., [a "Chaos Theory in Politics" anthology published in 2014](http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/19/2/reviews/1.html) and a [similar anthology in 2009](https://www.press.umich.edu/2151036/chaos_theory_in_the_social_sciences). The reviews of the articles that are out there are not generous. As mentioned above, chaos theory is largely used as a metaphor, and the authors are often woefully deficient in understanding and applying the mathematical concepts involved, so chaos theory isn't adding much value in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

[Chaos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) suggests that when a small thing happens, there are two possible results.  In one result, the small thing has no significant impact on anything else and fades away.  In the other result, the one small thing acts as a tipping point on adjacent activities, which then influence their adjacent activities.  This continues transitively until the one small thing is seen as something big because of what it caused.  This is called the [Butterfly Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect).

Consider a set of standing dominoes in a line.  If I tip a domino at the end of the line away from the line, then nothing happens.  If I tip it towards the rest of the line, it knocks over the entire line.  And this experiment is repeatable.  I can set up the line again or get a different set of dominoes and get the same result.

The problem in political science is that it is hard to compare things.  We can't go back and redo the sixties with John F. Kennedy not being assassinated.  So we don't know if the sixties would have played out the same.  We can only guess if someone else would have stepped forward to be the Republican nominee for president in 1964.  Assuming Kennedy beat whoever that was, we can only speculate whether he would have had enough political capital to pass the Civil Rights Act.

Stephen King wrote a book speculating that if Kennedy had not been assassinated, the country would have been overcome with riots.  Is he right?  Wrong?  For the most part, we can only speculate, as King did.

We can carry things back further from what is considered to be the significant event.  For example, Adolf Hitler was a painter (of pictures, not houses).  At one time in his aborted career, he went to a mostly Jewish group and asked for support.  He did not receive it.  If he had instead become a minor artist, would World War II not have happened?  Or was John Maynard Keynes correct in his [assertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Economic_Consequences_of_the_Peace) that the peace terms were overly harsh and destined to lead to another war.  And it's not like Hitler was the only anti-Semitic member of the National Socialist Workers Party of Germany.

In 1928, Calvin Coolidge considered whether he wanted to support Herbert Hoover for president.  Coolidge hated Hoover and thought that he was an idiot, totally unsuitable to be president.  However, Coolidge worried that if he did not support Hoover, that a Democrat might become president.  What would have happened if Hoover had expressed his feelings?  Perhaps Hoover would not have been president and a Democrat would have.  Then when the system collapsed into the Great Depression, a Democrat would have been in charge rather than a Republican.

The already reeling Democrats, would have been destroyed and replaced by some new party.  Without Hoover abandoning the black vote in favor of Southern whites, Republicans would have retained their overwhelming support among blacks.  Things could have been very different.

Alternately, Hoover might have won anyway and Coolidge's opinion would be lost in the annals of history.

We don't know.  We can't know.  We can only speculate as to what extent these singular events had on history.  Are these butterfly effects?  Or pebbles dropping into a pond and smoothing away into nothing?